# How would you solve this.

Tags: numerical-methods

Find the constants $c_0, c_1,$ and $x_1$ so that the quadrature formula
$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx = c_0 f(0) + c_1 f(x_1)$$
has the highest possible degree of precision.

Comment: $x_1=1$, $c_0=c_1=1/2$. You do better!

Comment: @Amzoti yeah! edited

Answer (score 0):

By the [mean value theorem for integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_integration), there exists some $\xi\in(0,1)$ such that $$f(\xi)=\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm d x.$$ Hence, choose $c_0=0$, $c_1=1$, and $x_1=\xi$ to obtain exact precision.

Of course, this doesn't really help much if you're supposed to *find* the value of $\xi$ because you don't know it in the first place.

Comment: Presumably the answer is supposed to be independent of $f$ in a certain class...and computable.